# window.innerHeight returning wrong value in iOS 11

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, wkwebview

I have a cordova iOS app running on the latest version of both cordova (8) and cordova-ios (4.5.4) to date. I recently started looking into updating the app to use `WKWebView` as opposed to the default `UIWebView`, but I have found out that in iOS 11 (testing on an iPad mini) the webview sometimes report the wrong innerHeight.

This is the relevant code in the index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">

<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

This is how I'm trying to read the property (all after the `deviceready` handler):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var calcHeight = window.screen.height - window.innerHeight;
}
```

`window.screen.height` always evaluates to 1024 which is fine, but `window.innerHeight` sometimes returns 1004 (which is the expected value), but some other times it returns 460.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The keyboard widget doesn't happen to appear sometimes does it?

Comment: @Keith, thanks for your response. I actually have a couple of inputs in that html page and I don't seem to have any issues with the soft keyboard whatsoever.

Comment: Soft keyboards in browsers effect innerHeight, what I normally do is attach to the window resize event to update when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the viewport tag as per Apple's specifications?

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: I did. I actually put that in the question.

Comment: Hmm.. does document.documentElement.clientHeight work correctly?

Comment: I have been able to test in a couple of different iPads with iOS versions and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` seems to return the right value. Thanks for the help.

Comment: iOS bug seems to still be in 15.5 and this fix appears to still work (although I am concerned with clientWidth). @EricNail since this is the accepted answer you might want to move the real solution from your comment to the body of the answer.